# upper bound on moduli of complex roots of a polynomial

Tags: calculus

Let $P(z)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\dots+a_n$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients.
Show that $\max |z_i| \le \max\left(2|a_1|,2 |\frac{a_2}{a_1}|,\dots,2|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}|,|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}|\right)$

Show that if coefficients are positive and real, then this upper bound can be strengthened as :

$\max |z_i| \le \max\left(a_1,\frac{a_2}{a_1},\dots,\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n-2},\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}\right)$

where $z_i$ are its roots.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: let $r$ be the max of roots and $M$ be the max on the right (first one). We can show that $r \le M(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} |a_1| r^{-1}+ \dots \frac 1 2 |a_{n-2}| r^{-(n-2)}+|a_{n-1}|r^{-(n-1)})$ only using triangle inequality. If we can show that $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} |a_1| r^{-1}+ \dots \frac 1 2 |a_{n-2}| r^{-(n-2)}+|a_{n-1}|r^{-(n-1)}) \le 1$ it will conclude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r=\max |z_i|$ and $M=\max\left(2|a_1|,2 |\frac{a_2}{a_1}|,\dots,2|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}|,|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}|\right)$

If $r=0$, the result is clear. Then suppose that $r>M>0$

If $z$ is a complex root of our polynomial, we have : $-z^n=a_1z^{n-1}+\dots +a_n$

So $|z^n|=|z|^n=|a_1z^{n-1}+\dots +a_n| \le |a_1||z|^{n-1}+|a_2||z|^{n-2}+\dots +|a_n|$

More precisely, we have $r^n \le |a_1|r^{n-1}+|a_2|r^{n-2}+\dots +|a_n|\le \frac{1}{2}Mr^{n-1}+\frac 1 2 |a_1|Mr^{n-2}+\dots +\frac{1}{2}|a_{n-2}|Mr+|a_{n-1}|M$

$\iff r\le M\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}|a_k|r^{-k}+|a_{n-1}|r^{-(n-1)}\right)$ by dividing by $r^{n-1}$ both sides

So $r\le \frac{1}{2} M+\frac{1}{2}M\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}|a_k|r^{-k}+M|a_{n-1}|r^{-(n-1)}$

Then $\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}|a_k|r^{-k}+|a_{n-1}|r^{-(n-1)}=\frac1 2|a_1|r^{-1}+\frac1 2|a_2|r^{-2}+\dots +|a_{n-1}|r^{-(n-1)}\le \frac{1}{4}Mr^{-1}+\frac{1}{4}M|a_1|r^{-2}+\dots +\frac{1}{2}M|a_{n-2}|r^{-(n-1)}= \frac 1 2Mr^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}|a_1|r^{-1}+\dots+|a_{n-2}|r^{-(n-2)}\right)$

Then $r\le \frac{1}{2} M+\frac 1 2M^2r^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}|a_1|r^{-1}+\dots+|a_{n-2}|r^{-(n-2)}\right)=\frac{1}{2} M+\frac 1 4M^2r^{-1}+\frac 1 2M^2r^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}|a_1|r^{-1}+\dots+|a_{n-2}|r^{-(n-2)}\right)$

We can continue recursively (as we notice that the largest index on $a_i$ is decreasing) and we get that :

$r\le \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{M}{2}\right)^kr^{-(k-1)}\le M\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k=M\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\le M$, which is a contradiction.

We proved the first part.
(I could have written some mistakes but this doesn't affect the conclusion)

For the second part, this method doesn't seem to work...
We just need to expand $(z-M)P(z)$ where $M$ is the other max and bound it with triangle inequality to solve it.